# Time series prediction model

Tags: time-series

I'm a programmer/database developer, not a statistician, so I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction here. I've got enrollment data for conference sessions going back 5 years. I have weekly enrollment figures for each session 9 months before the start of each session and then I have the final tally after the session took place.

I basically want to use this data to predict if a session will meet its minimum enrollment (40%) or if it will need to be cancelled. So, at its most basic, I have a session ID, a weekly enrollment number, and a max session size. The goal is to be able to cancel sessions earlier than they are currently cancelled (at the last minute).

Since I also have a lot of demographic data on past session participants, I'm assuming that could be added into the mix. But right now I am just trying to keep it as simple as possible until I'm able to learn more.

At this point, I'm mainly looking for the right way to frame the problem and for resources. Grateful for any pointers.  Thanks.